# access anchor tag with innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have system generated anchor tag and it doesn't contain id or class.
Only thing I know that it has fixed inner html(like "Clear").
Can we access this anchor tag with inner html. 
So on click of this I can hide another div tag.

```css
.wrap-div{

width:70px;
height:100px;
background-color:black;
}

#submit{

display:block;
position: relative;

}
```

```html
<div class='wrap-div' ></div>
<div id="submit">                            
<a onclick="fun1();" href="javascript:{}">   
                             Apply                            
</a>                             |                        
<a onclick="fun2()" href="javascript:{}"> 
                           Clear                    
</a>  

</div>
```

Comment: xy problem why can't you add a class/id to the links?

Comment: `I have system generated anchor tag` if they're system generated, can't you amend the system that generates them? It's always best to fix at the source, rather than patch later down the line

Comment: @madalinivascu it is coming from sharepoint  inbuild display template

Comment: Is 'onclick="fun2()"' system generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute equals selector

```
$("a[onclick='fun2()']")
```

```js
$("a[onclick='fun2()']").css("color", "red");
```

```css
.wrap-div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
#submit {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap-div'></div>
<div id="submit">
  <a onclick="fun1();" href="javascript:{}">   
                             Apply                            
</a> |
  <a onclick="fun2()" href="javascript:{}"> 
                           Clear                    
</a> 

</div>
```

or `:contains()`

```
$("a:contains('Clear')")
```

```js
$("a:contains('Clear')").css("color", "sienna");
```

```css
.wrap-div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
#submit {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap-div'></div>
<div id="submit">
  <a onclick="fun1();" href="javascript:{}">   
                             Apply                            
</a> |
  <a onclick="fun2()" href="javascript:{}"> 
                           Clear                    
</a> 

</div>
```

Comment: Can I prioritize function call    $("a:contains('Clear')").click(function() {   
   //my Code        
  });  after system generated onclick="fun2()"

Comment: @pawankotak What does `fun2()` do? You should be able to change or remove the attribute with `.attr()`, you can then use `$("a:contains('Clear')").click(function() { fun2(); //my Code })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in jQuery:

```
$('#submit a').each(function(i, item) {
  if($(item).text() == 'Clear')
  {
      // here you have access to that a tag
      console.log(item);
      return;
  }
})​;
```